# Interface class with method overloads?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Suppose I have some types

```
class A {…};
class B {…};
class C {…};
...
```

And I have some other classes that does various things on objects of these types

```
class process1
{
public:
    void do_stuff(std::vector<A>& …);
};

class process2
{
public:
    void do_stuff(std::vector<B>& …);
    void do_stuff(std::vector<C>& …);
};

...
```

These "process" classes share some common interface (`do_stuff()`), so naturally I want to make an class/template to "regulate" how these classes should be written. I want to have something like

```
template <class T>
class process_interface
{
public:
    virtual void do_stuff(std::vector<T>& …)
    {
        // Default implementation.
    }

    // I might also want this.
    // virtual void do_other_stuff(std::vector<T>& …) = 0;
};
```

and let `process1` and `process2` derive from it. In this way I'm saying that all "process" classes should have a `do_stuff()`, and that one doesn't necessarily need to write it explicitly because there a default version.

But of course this doesn't work, because `process2` has 2 versions of `do_stuff()`. (Some other "process" classes may have more.) So is there a way to achieve what I want to with this "interface" class/template? I was thinking using a variadic template but I suppose that won't work either.

For now what I have is this:

```
class process_interface
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void do_stuff(std::vector<T>& …)
    {
        // Default implementation.
    }

    // template <class T>
    // void do_other_stuff(std::vector<T>& …)
    // {
    //     throw std::runtime_error("Nope.");
    // }
};
```

But it has problems. For one, `do_stuff()` cannot be virtual/pure virtual. And if I have other methods that need the same treatment, like the `do_other_stuff()` there, there's no way to force the subclasses to have a `do_other_stuff()` for each type that one can `do_stuff()` on.

Comment: Inheritance is not the right way to share common code. You can do that with simple composition.

Comment: No, overloading and overriding are  mutually exclusive. Yet another of the evil traits of virtual functions.

Comment: @Frank, so what should I do in this case?

Comment: What about moving the template from the method to the class?

Comment: @Dani, that's the 1st version of `process_interface`. It doesn't work because of the overloading in `process2`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make `process2` (and all classes with need of more `do_stuff()` a sort of variadic self inheriting class.

Something as

```
template <typename...>
struct process2;

template <typename T>
struct process2<T> : public process_interface<T>
 { };


template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct process2<T0, Ts...> : public process_interface<T0>,
                             public process2<Ts...>
 {
   using process_interface<T0>::do_stuff;
   using process2<Ts...>::do_stuff;
 };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
class D {};

template <typename T>
struct process_interface
 {
   virtual void do_stuff (std::vector<T> const &)
    { }
 };

struct process1 : public process_interface<A>
 { };

template <typename...>
struct process2;

template <typename T>
struct process2<T> : public process_interface<T>
 { };


template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct process2<T0, Ts...> : public process_interface<T0>,
                             public process2<Ts...>
 {
   using process_interface<T0>::do_stuff;
   using process2<Ts...>::do_stuff;
 };

int main ()
 {
   process1           p1;
   process2<B, C, D>  p2;

   p1.do_stuff(std::vector<A>{});
   p2.do_stuff(std::vector<B>{});
   p2.do_stuff(std::vector<C>{});
   p2.do_stuff(std::vector<D>{});
 }
```

Starting from C++17, there is no needs of a self-recursive `process2`: you can use unpacking `using` and `process2` simply become

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct process2 : public process_interface<Ts>...
 {
   using process_interface<Ts>::do_stuff ... ; 
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your first version and use multiple inheritance:

```
class process2 : process_interface<B>, process_interface<C> {
public:
    using process_interface<B>::do_stuff;
    using process_interface<C>::do_stuff;
};
```

Note the using declarations bring `do_stuff` in the base classes to `process2` itself, so both can be found by name lookup, then participate in overload resolution.

[A Complete Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W3MbScxXilI4CKHH)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case to illustrate why common functionallity sharing is better handled through composition than inheritance.

Here's a super simple way of getting what you want without any inheritance whatsoever:

```
class common_interface {
   template <class T>
   void do_stuff(std::vector<T>& …)
   {
     //...
   }
};

class process_1 {
  common_interface common_;
public:
   void do_stuff(std::vector<A>& v) {
     common_.do_stuff(v);
     //...
   }
};

class process_2 {
  common_interface common_;
public:
   void do_stuff(std::vector<B>& v) {
     common_.do_stuff(v);
     //...
   }

  void do_stuff(std::vector<C>& v) {
     common_.do_stuff(v);
     //...
  }
};
```

Comment: This could work. But it seems to have the same problems as my 2nd version of `process_interface`, in that it doesn't force the subclasses to have a set of `do_stuff()` with the correct arguments.

Comment: @MetroWind The compiler will just tell you if try to use a version that's not implemented. And if you are missing an implementation that's not used anywhere, then it's dead code and is better left unwritten.